# Code for imputing values in a specific column using the particular rows Index number or unique ID?

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, data-science

I'd like to input certain value in a particular column. my data looks something like:

```
LoanID  Married  ApplicantIncome  CoapplicantIncome  Credit_History
LP00135   NaN        33460             16000               1.0
LP00234   Yes        55000             70000               1.0
LP00432   No         12000             0                   0.0
```

(I also know the index no. corresponding to each row, in this case  for the 1st row its 104)
As we can see in the 1st line, the applicant is obviously married as there is an entry for coapplicant income.

Is there a way I can directly impute "Yes" into in that column for that particular row using the Index no. or LoanID as these two are unique for each row?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to include an *attempt* at solving the issue in your question, seems like your trying to use SO to complete your homework assignments, considering the chain of questions you've been asking....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use `.loc` for this:

```
df.loc[(df['CoapplicantIncome'] > 0) & pd.isnull(df['Married']), 'Married'] = 'Yes'
```

This makes the assumption, of course, that the coapplicant will always be the applicant's married partner.

Comment: I'd like to impute "Yes" for that specific field only. Is there a way to do that without replacing or duplicating the entries in all other fields under "Married' when CoaaplicantsIncome > 0?

Comment: @uharsha33, if I understand correctly, you can just add the condition of 'Married' being null, as per update.

Comment: Thanks, that worked too. Could you have a look at one of my other question and help me out?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49088259/how-to-impute-values-in-a-column-when-certain-conditions-are-fulfilled-in-other/49088287#49088287

Comment: Actually, the answer had all 3 cases grouped together for that question, I wanted individual code for each case. Combining it makes more sense, but as a beginner I'm trying to break it down as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can using `fillna`

```
df.Married=df.Married.fillna(df.CoapplicantIncome.gt(0).map({True:'Yes'}))
df
Out[83]: 
    LoanID Married  ApplicantIncome  CoapplicantIncome  Credit_History
0  LP00135     Yes            33460              16000             1.0
1  LP00234     Yes            55000              70000             1.0
2  LP00432      No            12000                  0             0.0
```

Comment: I don't understand, you've not used Index number or LoanID number here, does that mean your code will replace all fields in Married column with entries in CoapplicantIncome to "Yes"?

Comment: @uharsha33 only replace those NaN to Yes , when CoapplicantIncome  is greater than 0, other Not NaN value will as same as before

Comment: Oh, just to clarify, your code will only replace the "NaN" values under 'Married' when the CoapplicantIncome > 0, and not affect all the other "Yes/No" values under 'Married' when CoapplicantIncome > 0?

Comment: @uharsha33 yes :-)

Comment: Perfect :-)     Could you have a look at my other question and see if you can answer it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49088259/how-to-impute-values-in-a-column-when-certain-conditions-are-fulfilled-in-other/49088287#49088287

Comment: @uharsha33 if this is what you want , can you consider upvote and accept ?